# Structure function in DIS calculation step

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, dirac-matrices

There is one step in the calculation that I am not understanting, but there are many things to present so one can understand and help me:

i)$k^2$ and $k_T^2$ are small, so can be neglected;

ii)$k^\mu=\xi p^\mu+\frac{k^2+k^2_T}{2\xi}n^\mu+k_T^\mu;$

iii) $n^\mu=(\frac{1}{2P},0,0,\frac{-1}{2P});\;\;p^\mu=(P,0,0,P);$

iv)  $q^\mu=q^\mu_T+\nu n^\mu;$

We have the expression for the structure function:
$$F_2=\frac{e_q^2}{2}\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}Tr[\gamma^an_a(\gamma^ck_c+\gamma^dq_d)\gamma^bn_b B(p,q)](\text{other terms});$$ So aparently the bracketed term turns into $x\gamma^\alpha n_\alpha$ where $x=\frac{Q^2}{2p\cdot q}$ and $B(p,q) $ is some part of the diagram that dont matters for this step.

Please i thinks it is a property of the gamma matrices but i'm not getting anywhere opening the definition $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2g^{\mu\nu}\times \boldsymbol{I}$

Follows the textbook part of it "Ellis and stirling- QCD and collider physic
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please provide context to your problem. You should really define the equations you use, and what each term represents. We like it so that others who come to this site will also learn something. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a reference and what exactly your question is?

Comment: Please write out acronyms and define symbols